# Change the value in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

Me need to change value on `right labels`. But first I need to change the `first four rows` and then the `last three rows`. So when i select `first four rows` i add in `right label` number `1200` for `four rows`, and then i select `last three rows` in `right label` number `1500` for `last three rows`.

For change data in `right label` i use button `Задать цену` at the end, all this data must be in the `array`.

[image: example[1]]

**At the end i want to see this result.**

[image]

Comment: on button Action you want to replace right Label Values ?

Comment: show code what are you doing... and on what event you want to update value ?

Comment: on tableview row select, you want to change the value of right label to 1200(first four row) and 1500 (last 3 row), irrespective of which cell clicked first? and are you sure there will be only 7 rows there? 

and at last, on button click.. get those right label values in an array? did i understand it right??

Comment: @AshwinShrestha yes, you understand correct. About first four and last three rows their may be `maximum 24 values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To replace Row Data in DidSelect Delegate of TableView**

**table View Class**

```
import UIKit

class demoTableVC: UIViewController {

    let leftLabelArray : [String] = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]
    var rightLabelArray : [String] = ["0","0","0","0","0","0","0"]

    @IBOutlet weak var demoTableView: UITableView!

    @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any)
    {
        //Get the updated Array
        print(rightLabelArray)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        demoTableView.delegate = self
        demoTableView.dataSource = self

    }
}

extension demoTableVC : UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        //Return Number of Rows
        return leftLabelArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        //Define cell 
        let cell = self.demoTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TableCellClass

        //Update Values 
        cell.leftLabel.text = leftLabelArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.rightLabel.text = rightLabelArray[indexPath.row]

        //Return cell
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        //Switch case statement
        switch indexPath.row
        {
        //This Handle your first 4 case of Table Cell
        case 0,1,2,3:
            rightLabelArray[indexPath.row] = "1200"
            self.demoTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
            break;

        //This Handle your next 3 case of Table Cell
        case 4,5,6:
            rightLabelArray[indexPath.row] = "1500"
            self.demoTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 80
    }


}
```

**Table Cell class**

```
import UIKit

class TableCellClass: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var leftLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var rightLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

**Note** This code is Written for 7 static Rows using switch case statements in case if number of Rows increases more than 7 then need to modify the switch case statement

This will work in flow to replace first 7 index

**Storyboard**

[image]

Comment: but as per question, the number of row may vary.. you cant just use switch case to give label, a value.. this is not correct

Comment: I Edited my answer after reading your Comment on post Asking about will there be Static 7 rows  , and over all Question Holder want to replace first four index with 1200 means **Index - 0,1,2,3** and the other 3 means **index - 4,5,6** , this example willl provide a brief idea what Question holder need to do Actually, if number of Rows increases in case , user can Do modifications in Code, Thanks

Comment: I added a note and some comments for justification

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have a count for your number of rows in a variable devices = AnyObject

now make array with the arraysize

```
 var myInts = [Int](repeating: 0, count: devices.count)
```

in method,

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row <= 3 {
            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? YourCell
            cell?.rightLabel.text = "1200"
            myInts[indexPath.row] = "1200"
        }
        else if (indexPath.row < devices.count) && (indexPath.row >= devices.count-3) {
            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? YourCell
           cell?.rightLabel.text = "1500"
           myInts[indexPath.row] = "1500"
        }
}
```

now on button click

```
print(myInts)
```